# MemSQL generate UUID

Tags: uuid, singlestore

I would like to migrate the database from MySQL to MemSQL. Original database use UUID as ID generated by function `UUID()`. Is there any possibility, how to use a similar function for generating those ID's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MemSQL does not have a built-in UUID() function, but you can generate unique ids in various ways, depending on what you need them for, such as:

- Generate random hashes. You can do this by e.g. `SHA1(RAND())`, or to get 16 bytes of randomness `CONCAT(SUBSTRING(SHA1(RAND()), 1, 16), SUBSTRING(SHA1(RAND()), 1, 16))`.
- Use auto_increment to generate ids unique within a table
- Generate UUIDs in the application side

If you need them to follow the UUID format, you can reformat them with string functions